# Get website thumbnail snapshot with C++

Tags: c++, thumbnails, snapshot

Is there any way to capture an image of a web page using a C++ CGI?  I've been searching high and low, and while I've found a number of implementations in everything from Perl to C#, haven't been able to find any implementations in C++.

The idea is for a user visiting a site to be able to specify a URL.  The script would then take a picture of the URL's website, and then show load it to the C++ CGI website I am building.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Example in Perl:
[Webthumb](http://www.boutell.com/webthumb/)

Comment: What code did the C# implementations use? Almost anything you can write in C# can be easily ported to a Win32 C++ app.

Comment: As in, a method where the argument is a URL?

Comment: @Bart - aye, as in a method that would take in a URL as an argument, and take a picture of the said URL, and save it to a folder (or show it directly on another website).  Basically, I am developing a CGI website in C++, and as part of the requirement I need to be able to show webthumbs of websites.  Though since nobody in their right mind would write a CGI website in C++, there source material is a bit short :)

Comment: @Cody - will try to find those again... though I think they required special C# libraries...

Comment: Also, thumbnail is presumably the favicon? That's a simple HTTP GET. If it's more, there are about a zillion webservices that will allow you to get a thumbnail using a cgi, or you can just host such a service youself and call it. That way, it perhaps need not be in c++?

Comment: @elfsareus: http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/ and [PoCo](http://pocoproject.org/docs/). Also look here for more [C/C++ webserver library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library)

Comment: @sehe - Hmm, as in http:/www.boutell.com/webthumb/ just for c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to render the webpage in order to create a snapshot. To render the page in C++ you need to include a browser engine. You can do this easily using Qt (a toolkit for c++).
This is taken from the documentation of Qt and is all you need to show a webpage.

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView(ui->centralWidget);
view->load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
view->show();
```

The view object has a loadFinished signal. You could connect some code to this signal. When the page is rendered you tak a snapshot as described [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_take_snapshot_in_Qt).
It boils down to:

```
QPixmap::grabWindow(mainwindow->winId())
```

When you have got the screenshot you can return the bytes on stdout from your cgi and your done.